# Vmware Server Console stops responding to clicks

Tags: 11.04, unity, server, vmware, console

I had installed vmware-server-console just fine.  But when yoou open it an as soon as you click in a virtual machine, thats it, the app stop working but not freeze, it just stops recognizing where you click, everywhere you click it puts the cursor inside the VM, you cant switch VMs, cant do rigth clic on the left menu, theres not even the toolbar.

I try login in with a classic ubuntu session, but this behavior persist.  Is there a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

From the VMware website knowledge base:

> This issue occurs if the virtual machine is in a non-responsive state.
>   To confirm the virtual machine is not responding, check if the virtual
>   machine can be accessed with Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP),
>   or if it responds to pings. If it cannot, the virtual machine is
>   non-responsive and must be restarted.
>
> To restart the virtual machine:
>
> - Right-click the virtual machine, and click Power Off.
> - Right-click the virtual machine, and click Power On.

[Reference](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009869)